# How can I prioritize SimPy events that occur at the same time?

Tags: python, simpy

I'm running into an issue in my SimPy simulation where several events are occurring at the same time step in the wrong order. Specifically, I'm modeling a production line where machines periodically fail and receive maintenance. When a machine is repaired at time `t1`, it should resume production at that time. However, the order in which the events occur is

1. check if repair complete
2. complete repair
3. if repaired, resume production

When I want it to be

1. complete repair
2. check if repair complete
3. if repaired, resume production

Is there any way to change the order in which the events are executed?

Here is a minimum example of the problem I'm having:

```py
import random
import simpy

class machine:
    def __init__(self, env, process_time):
        self.env = env
        self.process_time = process_time

        self.remaining_process_time = process_time
        self.failed = False
        self.parts_made = 0

        env.process(self.production())
        env.process(self.maintenance())

    def production(self):
        while True:
            while self.remaining_process_time:
                if random.random() < 0.1:
                    # machine fails                
                    print(f'Machine failed at t={self.env.now}')
                    self.failed = True
                    while self.failed:
                        # wait for maintenance to finish
                        yield self.env.timeout(1)

                    print(f'Resuming production at t={self.env.now}\n')

                yield self.env.timeout(1)
                self.remaining_process_time -= 1
            self.parts_made += 1
            self.remaining_process_time = self.process_time

    def maintenance(self):
        while True:
            while not self.failed:
                # wait for failure to occur
                yield self.env.timeout(1)

            print(f'Starting repair at t={self.env.now}')
            ttr = random.randint(1,8)
            print(f'TTR={ttr}')
            yield self.env.timeout(ttr)
            self.failed = False
            self.remaining_process_time = self.process_time
            print(f'Finished repair at t={self.env.now}')

random.seed(1234)
env = simpy.Environment()
system = machine(env, 5)
env.run(until=50)
```

And the output is:

```
Machine failed at t=2
Starting repair at t=2
TTR=1
Finished repair at t=3
Resuming production at t=4

Machine failed at t=6
Starting repair at t=6
TTR=6
Finished repair at t=12
Resuming production at t=12

Machine failed at t=14
Starting repair at t=15
TTR=1
Finished repair at t=16
Resuming production at t=16

Machine failed at t=23
Starting repair at t=24
TTR=8
Finished repair at t=32
Resuming production at t=32

Machine failed at t=37
Starting repair at t=38
TTR=2
Finished repair at t=40
Resuming production at t=40

Machine failed at t=42
Starting repair at t=43
TTR=2
Finished repair at t=45
Resuming production at t=45
```

For the first failure, the repair correctly finished at `t=3`, but production doesn't resume until `t=4`. Looking at the third failure, the failure occurs at `t=14` but the repair doesn't start until `t=15`. It seems these processes running in parallel (`production` and `maintenance`) create issues and check the conditions inconsistently, so my though is that I need to redesign them altogether.

Comment: Could you share some code?  The answer could be as simple as just re-ordering some lines of code, or may require event logic.

Comment: I believe it is a duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085532/how-can-i-set-priority-on-simpy-process-callbacks/33278669#33278669)

Comment: I've added an example that should be helpful in explaining my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to arise when multiple processes are calling `self.env.timeout(1)` simultaneously. Here is a solution I found:

```py
class machine:
    def __init__(self, env, process_time):
        self.env = env
        self.process_time = process_time

        self.remaining_process_time = process_time
        self.failed = False
        self.parts_made = 0

        env.process(self.production())

    def production(self):
        while True:
            while self.remaining_process_time:
                if random.random() < 0.1:
                    # machine fails                
                    print(f'Machine failed at t={self.env.now}')
                    self.failed = True
                    yield self.env.process(self.maintenance())

                    print(f'Resuming production at t={self.env.now}\n')

                yield self.env.timeout(1)
                self.remaining_process_time -= 1
            self.parts_made += 1
            self.remaining_process_time = self.process_time

    def maintenance(self):
        print(f'Starting repair at t={self.env.now}')
        ttr = random.randint(1,8)
        print(f'TTR={ttr}')
        yield self.env.timeout(ttr)
        self.remaining_process_time = self.process_time
        print(f'Finished repair at t={self.env.now}')

random.seed(1234)

env = simpy.Environment()
system = machine(env, 5)
env.run(until=50)
```

This code produces the output I expect.

```py
Machine failed at t=2
Starting repair at t=2
TTR=1
Finished repair at t=3
Resuming production at t=3

Machine failed at t=5
Starting repair at t=5
TTR=6
Finished repair at t=11
Resuming production at t=11

Machine failed at t=13
Starting repair at t=13
TTR=1
Finished repair at t=14
Resuming production at t=14

...
```

Comment: You can take a look at [The Machine Shop Example](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/machine_shop.html) in the simpy documentation for inspiration on how to do multiple machines and repairmen using simpy's Resources :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to change your code to avoid the scenario you describe. The code design you describe is sensitive to event process time/order and others might make a mistake in future revisions even though you put your order of events correctly.

If you change the code design so that the production machine waits for the repair instead of periodically checking then you should avoid the problem.

The process then would be:

1. Production machine broken; Wait for repairs.
2. Repairman completes repairs; Notify production machine.
3. Production machine resumes production.

Comment: I think you're right in that my issue arises due to multiple processes running in parallel, as shown in the example I added. I'll likely have to redesign the code.